# Magento 2: php version issue

Tags: magento2, php-7, ubuntu

on my ubuntu 16 server i have installed php and it show version

> PHP 7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May 31 2019
>   11:43:14) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine
>   v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.1.30-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

but when I run **phpinfo()** it show

> PHP Version 7.0.33-8+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Comment: PHP CLI has a different version with PHP for web server. Please try to upgrade your PHP version.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to do so

Comment: How many PHP version on your system?

Comment: /usr/bin/ shows  php7.0 , php7.1 ,  php7.3 ------- I want to use 7.1

Comment: What's your web server? Apache or Nginx?

Comment: I am using Apache

Comment: Google will help you. For example: https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-switch-between-multiple-php-versions-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks it works  :)

Answer (score 0):

We can have multiple php version 
kindly use below command to check list of your version and select the suitable one

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

Answer (score 0):

activate php 7.1

> sudo a2dismod php7.1

de-activate php 7.0 php 7.3

> sudo a2enmod php7.0
>
> sudo a2enmod php7.3

this configuration works for me